# How to partiallly update a model in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I built an api with django and I have a picture model that comprises an imagefield. I'm trying to perform a partial update

I already tried setting `partial = True`to the Serializer's definition

the serializer is

```py
class PictureSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ("id", "name", "picture", "button_1", "button_2", "button_3", "button_4")
        partial = True
```

the model is

```py
class Picture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures/", null=True, blank=True)
    button_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    button_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    button_3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    button_4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    printed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

the view is

```py
class PictureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Picture.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PictureSerializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose your `ViewSet`in `urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'pictures', PictureViewSet, base_name='picture')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Send `PATCH` request with JSON data you want to update to the exposed endpoint. Mind that PATCH requests go to instance endpoint of the instance you want to update so your URL will look like this: `.../pictures/<picture_id>`.

```
{
  "name": "updated_name"
}
```

You don't need the `partial = True` part.

Also when there are far less excluded fields than included fields in your serializer you can do:

```
class Meta:
    model = Picture
    exclude = ("printed", )
```

Comment: thank you, I just needed to do a PATCH instead of a PUT request